# How to fire UITapGestureRecognizer on a child view that is partially clipped by parent view?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

Setup: I have parent view A. It has a child view B. B is partially inside the bounds of A, but partially outside (A has clipsToBounds=false). I have attached UITapGestureRecognizer (UITGR) to B.

Observed: UITGR fires OK when I tap on the portion of B that is within the bounds of A. UITGR does NOT fire when I tap on the portion of B that is outside the bounds of A.

Expected/question: How do I make UITGR fire when I tap on the portion of B that is outside the bounds of A?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This quote will answer your question as to *why* it behaves like that:

> Touch events. The window object uses hit-testing and the responder chain to find the view to receive the touch event. In hit-testing, a window calls hitTest:withEvent: on the top-most view of the view hierarchy; this method proceeds by recursively calling pointInside:withEvent: on each view in the view hierarchy that returns YES, proceeding down the hierarchy until it finds the subview within whose bounds the touch took place. That view becomes the hit-test view.
>   ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW4))

One workaround is to create your own `UITapInSubviewsView` with the following definition for `hitTest`:

```
(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSEnumerator *reverseE = [self.subviews reverseObjectEnumerator];
    UIView *iSubView;
    while ((iSubView = [reverseE nextObject])) {

        UIView *viewWasHit = [iSubView hitTest:[self convertPoint:point toView:iSubView] withEvent:event];
        if(viewWasHit)
           return viewWasHit;
     }
     return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Then you use this class for your parent view.

(I found this code in a post from S.O. a few weeks ago, but I cannot seem to find it anymore; so just copied it from my project).

Answer (score 1):

Update of [@sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671858/sergio)'s answer for **Swift 4.2**:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let reversedSubviews = subviews.reversed()
    let hitSubview = reversedSubviews
        .first(where: { $0.hitTest(convert(point, to: $0), with: event) != nil })
    if hitSubview != nil {
        return hitSubview
    }

    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own hittest function for view A.

Also look at this question: [UITapGestureRecognizer not triggered in deep view hiearchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871946/uitapgesturerecognizer-not-triggered-in-deep-view-hiearchy/6872802#6872802)

Comment: Can you expand the answer a bit about the cause for this—is it because the default hittest ignores touches outside the parent view bounds? And I need to test myself whether the touch is in child bounds?